# Bazel error: An error occurred while getting the repository "npm"

Tags: node.js, google-maps, bazel

I recently cloned Google's js-examples repository that uses Bazel to run and build. On running the code in my computer, I kept getting the error "An error occurred while getting the repository npm"
I'm totally new to using bazel. Has anyone encountered such issue and how did you go about it?

Below is the link to the repo
[The link to the js-examples repo on github](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1xmo.png)

Above is the link to the error message

This is what I think is bazel trying to get npm

```
def _npm_install_impl(repository_ctx):
"""Core implementation of npm_install."""

_check_min_bazel_version("npm_install", repository_ctx)

is_windows_host = is_windows_os(repository_ctx)
node = repository_ctx.path(get_node_label(repository_ctx))
npm = get_npm_label(repository_ctx)

# Set the base command (install or ci)
npm_args = [repository_ctx.attr.npm_command]

npm_args.extend(repository_ctx.attr.args)

# Run the package manager in the package.json folder
if repository_ctx.attr.symlink_node_modules:
    root = str(repository_ctx.path(repository_ctx.attr.package_json).dirname)
else:
    root = str(repository_ctx.path(_workspace_root_prefix(repository_ctx)))

# The entry points for npm install for osx/linux and windows
if not is_windows_host:
    # Prefix filenames with _ so they don't conflict with the npm package `npm`
    repository_ctx.file(
        "_npm.sh",
        content = """#!/usr/bin/env bash# Immediately exit if any command fails. set -e (cd "{root}"; "{npm}" {npm_args})""".format(
            root = root,
            npm = repository_ctx.path(npm),
            npm_args = " ".join(npm_args),
        ),
        executable = True,
    )
else:
    repository_ctx.file(
        "_npm.cmd",
        content = """@echo off cd /D "{root}" && "{npm}" {npm_args}""".format(
            root = root,
            npm = repository_ctx.path(npm),
            npm_args = " ".join(npm_args),
        ),
        executable = True,
    )

_symlink_file(repository_ctx, repository_ctx.attr.package_lock_json)
_copy_file(repository_ctx, repository_ctx.attr.package_json)
_copy_data_dependencies(repository_ctx)
_add_scripts(repository_ctx)
_add_node_repositories_info_deps(repository_ctx)

result = repository_ctx.execute(
    [node, "pre_process_package_json.js", repository_ctx.path(repository_ctx.attr.package_json), "npm"],
    quiet = repository_ctx.attr.quiet,
)
if result.return_code:
    fail("pre_process_package_json.js failed: \nSTDOUT:\n%s\nSTDERR:\n%s" % (result.stdout, result.stderr))

env = dict(repository_ctx.attr.environment)
env_key = "BAZEL_NPM_INSTALL"
if env_key not in env.keys():
    env[env_key] = "1"
env["BUILD_BAZEL_RULES_NODEJS_VERSION"] = VERSION

repository_ctx.report_progress("Running npm install on %s" % repository_ctx.attr.package_json)
result = repository_ctx.execute(
    [repository_ctx.path("_npm.cmd" if is_windows_host else "_npm.sh")],
    timeout = repository_ctx.attr.timeout,
    quiet = repository_ctx.attr.quiet,
    environment = env,
)

if result.return_code:
    fail("npm_install failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stdout, result.stderr))

remove_npm_absolute_paths = Label("//third_party/github.com/juanjoDiaz/removeNPMAbsolutePaths:bin/removeNPMAbsolutePaths")

# removeNPMAbsolutePaths is run on node_modules after npm install as the package.json files
# generated by npm are non-deterministic. They contain absolute install paths and other private
# information fields starting with "_". removeNPMAbsolutePaths removes all fields starting with "_".
print([node, repository_ctx.path(remove_npm_absolute_paths), root + "/node_modules"])
result = repository_ctx.execute(
    [node, repository_ctx.path(remove_npm_absolute_paths), root + "/node_modules"],
)

if result.return_code:
    fail("remove_npm_absolute_paths failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stdout, result.stderr))

_symlink_node_modules(repository_ctx)

_create_build_files(repository_ctx, "npm_install", node, repository_ctx.attr.package_lock_json)
```

Comment: Each sample is in a branch of its own if you want to use that instead. The Bazel usage isn't really necessary. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple#clone-sample for how to clone the sample.

Comment: Was just wondering why that error came up. I'll check the link anyway, thanks!